# Error in loading image from database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I used a dialog box to open and insert an image into a database. I used this method

```
public void btn_LoadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog objOfd = new OpenFileDialog ();
        objOfd.Filter = "Image only. |*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.bmp;";
        DialogResult dr = objOfd.ShowDialog ();
        picbox_Input.Image = Image.FromFile (objOfd.FileName);
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        MessageBox.Show (ex.Message);
    }
```

Now I'm trying to get that image by handling a cell clicking event in the dataGridview. And I wrote these lines to get it done

```
Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
data = (Byte[])(objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][6]);
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>   Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Got it, wont happen again.